# Sending mail using PHP mail()

Tags: jquery, php

I've been trying to create a simple contact form using PHP. So, I've managed to get the form to work by plugging in values for all variables like so and it sends the email just fine:

```
$to = "andrew@mingbogu.com";
$subject = "Job";
$message = "Test";
$from = "example@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

However, as soon as I replace the values with $_REQUEST[var], the email gets sent to my Junk email with no from address:

```
$to = "andrew@mingbogu.com";
$subject = "Job";
$message = $_REQUEST['clientMessage'];
$from = $_REQUEST['clientEmail'];
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $from";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Screenshot of the email:
[image]

I'm getting the values through an ajax form using jQuery:

```
    var clientName = $("#name").val();
    window.alert(clientName);
    var clientEmail = $("#email").val();    
    window.alert(clientEmail);
    var clientMessage = $("#message").val();            
    window.alert(clientMessage);
     var data = "from=" + clientEmail + "&subject=" + clientName + "&message=" + clientMessage;
     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "email.php",
            data: data,
            success: function() {
                $("#loading").fadeOut(100).hide();
                $("#name").val(' ');
                $("#email").val(' ');
                $("#message").val(' ');
                $("#message-sent").fadeIn(100).show();
            }
        });
```

I've printed out `clientName`, `clientMessage`, and `clientEmail` all right before sending them into the ajax form and they all print out with correct values. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

HTML form:

```
 <form id="contactMe" data-abide>
 <input type="text" id="name">
  <input type="text" id="email">        
  <textarea  id="message"></textarea>
 <button type="submit" id="sendEmail" class="button">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Where is `data` defined? Also, use phpMailer or another lib to send emails instead of `mail()`.

Comment: Try adding these `$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";` **and**
`$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";` certain web sites will mark it as Spam if proper headers are not included.

Comment: @DCoder, my apologies, I added in `data` now, though it still doesn't seem to work.@Fred, where would I add those?

Comment: @Andrew Have you tried it without the `"from=" + clientEmail +`? Seems like you already took care of that with `$from = $_REQUEST['clientEmail'];`

Comment: @Andrew You would add those underneath `$headers = "From:" . $from;`, yet you would need to continue concatenates in `headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";` to be `$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";` the dot concatenates etc.

Comment: Just add those lines in the as a part of mail header

Comment: Use jQuery's `.serialize` to create `data` instead of building the string manually. Use `var_dump($_REQUEST)` to see if PHP receives your data properly.

Comment: @Andrew Actually try changing `$headers = "From:" . $from;` to `$headers = "From: $from";` that could be a factor. As per example #6 from the [**PHP manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) on `mail()` function.

Comment: @Fred, I tried changing it to that, and adding in the extra headers. The email no longer gets sent to the spam box, but it still shows up as unknown in the from field

Comment: @Andrew Making "some" headway, good. Have you tried my other suggestion just above, about changing `$headers = "From:" . $from;` **to** `$headers = "From: $from";` that could be it.

Comment: @Fred, I added that in but still nothing.

Comment: @Andrew Another thing may be the issue is your form field's name for the Email. Check if you haven't made a typo `clientEmail`. It's happened to many before, including myself. Need to check all avenues.

Comment: @Andrew Your `from` needs to be on top. Replace with `$headers = "From: $from"; $headers  .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n"; $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";` see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Andrew I'm glad your problem was resolved. However, the rule still applies to have your `from` on top, it's just good form/practice. (wink)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong variable to read the client email.  In your JS, you're pulling it into a variable called `clientEmail`, but then you're giving it the name `from` when passing the AJAX request:

```
var data = "from=" + clientEmail + "&subject=" + clientName + "&message=" + clientMessage;
```

So from within PHP, you should be accessing it as `$_REQUEST['from']`, not `$_REQUEST['clientEmail']`.

Comment: Thanks, that seem to did it!

Comment: Good catch Nick, definitely worth a +1 here, cheers. Glad someone figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a **"supplement"** to the [**accepted answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18040355/1415724) (good catch [**Nick**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1973299/nick-coons)), since the Email was treated as Junk/Spam.

Adding proper headers such as:

```
$headers  = "From: $from";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

will help reduce the chance of E-mail ending up in Junk or treated as Spam.

Certain web sites will mark it as Spam if proper headers are not included.

More information on the `mail()` can be found on [**PHP.net**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)